# Unable to retrieve value passed by getInitialProps() in a NextJS functional component

Tags: next.js

I have a stateless, functional component in NextJS where I'm trying to initialize some data upon load using `getInitialProps()`:

```
const LoginModal = props => (
  <p>{props.testdata}</p>
);

LoginModal.getInitialProps = () => ({ testdata: 'Some string value' });

export default LoginModal;
```

However, no matter what I do, it always renders with a blank `<p></p>`. Why isn't the value returned by `getInitialProps()` being read by the component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works here, It seems like your are using getInitialProps with a component outside the Pages directory, this function is available only inside the pages, https://github.com/zeit/next.js/#fetching-data-and-component-lifecycle